# Trim white space in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would love it if I could get some help on how to remove white space in the beginning and end of a table cell.  The following compares two cell, if different the newCell is highlighted in gray.  It partially works, except I need to trim the whitespace.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

This needs to work in IE8 so I applied the following in the to head section:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}
```

Code on the page:

```
$(".data table tbody tr.row").each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
            var oldCell = $(this);
            var newCell = $(this).next('td').length > 0 ? $(this).next('td') : null;
            if (index % 2 == 0 && newCell && oldCell.text().trim !== newCell.text().trim) {
                oldCell.css('backgroundColor', '#FFF');
                newCell.css({
                    'backgroundColor': '#666',
                    'color': '#FFF'
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `trim` is a function, so you need to call it with `str.trim()`, not just reference it with `str.trim`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Comment: Trim is a method, not a property. Google: "javascript trim".

Comment: Why would you avoid using jQuery own trim function  `$.trim($variable);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim` is a function, so you need to call it with `str.trim()`, not just reference it with `str.trim`.

```
oldCell.text().trim !== newCell.text().trim
```

should be

```
oldCell.text().trim() !== newCell.text().trim()
```

---

Since you're using jQuery, you can (as others have suggested) use it's built-in [`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) method instead of shimming in your own, which will work cross-browser.

```
var trimmedStr = $.trim(str);
```

Applied to your code:

```
$.trim(oldCell.text()) !== $.trim(newCell.text())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery so you can just replace the text in each cell with a trimmed version of itself:

```
$(".data table td").each(function(){
    $(this).text($.trim($(this).text()));
}
```